# Owner-Drawn Menus; Measuring and Drawing, how to tell if item is submenu item?

Tags: user-interface, winapi, menu, ownerdrawn

When an owner-drawn menu-item is being drawn is it possible to tell if it's a submenu item contrary to an item you'd find on the menu bar?

The goal being drawing the submenu's menu item's text aligned to the left and the width being a constant size, etc, unlike the menubar's menu item's, Apologies for my lack of knowledge, thanks for any help,

[image]

Comment: The `WM_DRAWITEM` message gives you the ID of the menu item being drawn, and since you created the menu you should know whether it's a sub-menu or top-level item?

Comment: Menu item ID's need not be unique. The same ID could be used for a menu bar item or a popup menu item, so it cannot be used to distinguish between either one. But you can associate arbitrary data with a menu item through the [`MENUITEMINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-menuiteminfow)'s `dwItemData` member.

Comment: Iinspectable, I quite like that idea, so long as I can still use the ItemData from the LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT & LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT as text after casting it to (LPCWSTR), if you don't mind me asking for an example of how I could do that; it'd be very appreaciated

Comment: Arbitrary data doesn't need to be unique either...